# I created a drive with VeraCrypt. Can I open the drive by entering the password as command line argument, as can be done for Windows Bit Locker?

Tags: powershell, veracrypt

I open a drive encrypted with BitLocker in Powershell with the following code.

Unlock-BitLocker -MountPoint "D:" –RecoveryPassword XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXX

I want to know how to do so with VeraCrypt.

veracrypt --password ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the VeraCrypt software for mounting a volume.

An example from
[VeraCrypt documentation](https://documentation.help/VeraCrypt/Command%20Line%20Usage.html):

> Mount a volume called myvolume.tc using the password MyPassword, as
> the drive letter X. VeraCrypt will open an explorer window and beep;
> mounting will be automatic:
>
> ```
> veracrypt /v myvolume.tc /l x /a /p MyPassword /e /b
> ```

See the above documentation for a description of the arguments
of the command.

You may call this command in PowerShell or in CMD.

Comment: I really don't know how to thank you

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).

Comment: Yes, your answer was useful. But I'm new and I don't know how to click the ✔ sign

Comment: You see it to the left of the answer you wish to accept.

Comment: Yes, I saw it on the left side and marked it. Again, I appreciate your help and I hope you will always be successful

Comment: Glad to have been of help.

Answer (score 1):

Though you cannot user PowerShell *per se* to open the drive without installing Veracrypt, you *can* open a Veracrypt container using Veracrypt with [command line arguments](https://documentation.help/VeraCrypt/Command%20Line%20Usage.html):

Windows style:

```
<path>\veracrypt /p <password>
```

Linux style:

```
<path>/veracrypt --p <password>
```

> "/password or /p  It must be followed by a parameter indicating the
> volume password. If the password contains spaces, it must be enclosed
> in quotation marks (e.g., /p ”My Password”)."

See also [ArchLinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/VeraCrypt) on *Mount volumes via fstab*.

Comment: Really great. It worked. You are really a great teacher. Thank you for your effort

Comment: @user1784708 If it works, then check that it answered your question, so others can search on that.